# How to prove a function is negligible?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function, negligible

My question essentially concerns how to prove if a function is **negligible**. As a matter of fact, though this question might seem very basic, it seems that most of the "proofs" of negligible concern comparing the the function with **another** negligible function and then asserting its status via laws of negligible functions.

What I am insisting on is a direct mathematical proof of proving how functions can be proven as negligible without comparison with any other function.

Comment: $2^{-n}$ is immediately obvious as negligble.

Comment: **Closely related:** ***[Proving that a function is negligible](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/347213/88955)*** at Math.SE as well as ***[Proving that a function is negligible](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/58355/12164)*** and ***[Property of negligible functions](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/56319/12164)*** here at our site.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by Dan Boneh:

> Different communities define these *(negligible and non-negligible)* differently

For **practitioners** they are basically a scalar $\varepsilon$, where, for example:

- $1/2^{30}$ is considered **non-negligible** because an event with this probability will probably happen after $2^{32}$ bits (1 gigabyte) of data
- $1/2^{80}$ is considered **negligible** because an event with this probability will not likely happen over the life of the key.

---

On the other hand, **in theory**, $\varepsilon$ is considered a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Saying that a **function is non-negligible** means that the function is bigger than **some** polynomial infinitely often:

$\exists d: \varepsilon(\lambda) \geqslant 1/\lambda^d$

Saying that a **function is negligible** means that the function is smaller than **all** polynomials:

$\forall d, \lambda \geqslant \lambda_d: \varepsilon(\lambda) \leqslant 1/\lambda^d$

where $\lambda_d$ is some integer depending on $d$ and, in both cases, $\lambda$ is an integer.

That said we can see that $\varepsilon(\lambda) = 2^{-\lambda} = 1/2^\lambda$ is negligible, because for any constant $d$ there is a sufficient large $\lambda$ so $\varepsilon(\lambda) \leqslant 1/\lambda^d$.

We can also verify the other example from the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/347213/proving-that-a-function-is-negligible) e-sushi provided: $\varepsilon(\lambda) = 2^{-100} = 1/2^{100}$ is non-negligible because if we set $d = 1000$ this function is clearly bigger than $1/\lambda^d$

$\square$

**Note:** Most of the answer is based on Dan Boneh's explanation about this subject on his [coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto/home/welcome)
**Note 2:** [This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/39356/unpacking-the-definition-of-negligible-non-negligible?rq=1) is also a nice answer on the subject